# How to resize something in MCedit?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, mcedit

I want to enlarge a small structure in my world to 4x it's size but I can't find anything that would allow me to do that. I've looked everywhere and can't find anything useful or not outdated. I've seen that it's supposed to be under the cloning tool, but there is just no option for it there, or anywhere else that I can find.

I'm using Minecraft 1.11.2 and MCedit2 2.0.0 beta 6.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not sure how to do this with MCEdit, there may be a filter somewhere.

However, seeing as you're not averse to third-party programs, I would recommend worldedit's //deform command.

```
//deform x/=2;y/=2;z/=2
```

That should double the size of your selection. Make sure to experiment on smaller selections first, as this does work in an interesting way. Your selection has to be double the size of what you want to enlarge on all sides, so if you're scaling up a 2by2by2 cube, you should make your selection so that there is one air block on every side of the cube (including diagonals).

The best way to do this is to select what you want to double, get the width, length, and height of the selection, and then expand by half of those values in each direction for every cardinal direction. So, for a 2by2by2 cube, I select the cube then do:

```
//expand 1 1 up (half height)
//expand 1 1 north (half width)
//expand 1 1 west (half length)
```